# iPhone: how to tag people on photo as Facebook app for iPhone does?

Tags: ios, facebook, tagging

I'm building a native iPhone app that takes a picture, does some funny stuff with it. I want the users to be able to tag their Facebook friends on the resulting picture, similar to what the Facebook app does. It seams that official facebook ios-sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk lacks this feature.

I wonder: is there some library or some advice that can help avoiding reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I've asked the similar question here and on official FB developer forum too but got no reply yet :(

Comment: one way around could be that .. you take a snapshot of your picture with tags (uilabels on image actually) and upload the snapshot on FB... but that's just a weird thought .

Comment: Tobias: image with labels is not what I want - I want normal picture with friends "tagged" the facebook way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple go here:
[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.addtag/](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245)

and it will build a photo tag URL for you on the right hand side. All you have to do is send a GET request with NSURLConnection, Apple has an example on how to send GET's and POST's:

[Here is Apple's example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245)

Comment: thank you Ajay. But this is what I call reinventing the wheel and I want to avoid. I'm looking for a "component" to plug in, configure and it works :). There should be something like that as there are at least several apps in the appstore with such functionality.

Comment: Finally I had to implement the tagging view myself

Comment: Great @xvga . Would you like to share your beautifully designed code with us here, so that others would be benefited. Thanks